# Why can't John arrest Danny for stealing gas?

Tags: bloodline

In S01E10, Danny already confessed to John (at the police station) about stealing the gasoline and supplying it to Wayne Lowry and also about working for Lowry:

> Danny: What are you gonna do? Arrest me for stealing gas? I'll be out in a month.

Danny is not arrested at this point.

Later in S01E12, John wants to find a way to arrest Danny as soon as possible due to the perceived threat to John's family:

> Marco: Until he breaks the law, there's absolutely nothing we could do. ... We don't have shit, you understand?

> John: Well, then, be creative.

Why can't John now arrest Danny for stealing gas?